# Group array elements into set of n

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

I have an array

```
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];
```

I want to group it into a set of n arrays such that first n elements in result[0] next n elements in result[1] and if any element is remaining it is discarded.

```
let sampleOutput = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]] for n = 7;
```

Here is my code:

```
function group5(arr, len) {
 let result = [];
 let loop=parseInt(arr.length/len)
 for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i+=len) {
  let x = []; let limitReached = false;
  for (let j=0; j<len; j++) {
   if (arr[i+j]) {
    x.push(arr[i+j]);
   } else {
    limitReached = true;
    break;
   }
  }
 if (!limitReached) {
  result.push(x);
 } else {
  break;
  }
 }
 return result;
}
```

But I am unable to get expected result. I have tried following things.

1. Map function
2. Running i loop to arr.len
3. Checking `arr.len % 7`
4. Creating an array for every third element.
5. This question is not duplicate of [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks) because I have to discard extra elements that can not be grouped into sets of n.
6. I have to keep the original array Immutable because I am using this on props in a child component. I need a function that does not modify the original array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Comment: Hello, thanks everyone. I settled for following solution. Consider this question closed.
    export function groupInChunks (arr, len) {
        let chunks = [];
        let i = 0;
        while((arr.length - i) >= len) {
            chunks.push(arr.slice(i, len + i));
            i+=len;
        }
        return chunks;
    }

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty straigthforward using Array.from

```js
const list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];

function chunkMaxLength(arr, chunkSize, maxLength) {
  return Array.from({length: maxLength}, () => arr.splice(0,chunkSize));
}

console.log(chunkMaxLength(list, 7, 2));
```

Comment: Which is why it is mentioned in [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10456644/402037) from the duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, if you compare the answers carefully, you'll find the differences. @Andreas  This answer is, in contrary to the other answer, doing what OP is asking for, and it's more performant than the Array.from approach in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

What about  :

```
function group5(arr, len) {
     let chunks = [];
     let copy   = arr.splice(); // Use a copy to not modifiy the original array
     while(copy.length > len) {
         chunks.push(copy.splice(0, len));
     }
     return chunks;
}
```

Comment: It is not discarding extra elements that can not be grouped into sets of 7. Yours answer results in [[0..6], [7..13], [14]] I don't want elements whose set can not be made of 7 elements.

Comment: I updated my answer, it's now returning the expected result.

Comment: Hi, This solution is quiet correct, What can I do to not modify the original array. The original array comes from props (react-native), hence I can't modify that.

Comment: I updated my answer again in order to not modify the original array. :)

Answer (score 2):

I usually prefer declarative solutions (`map`, `reduce`, etc), but in this case I think a `for` is more understandable:

```js
function groupArray(array, num) {
  const group = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += num) {
    group.push(array.slice(i, i + num));
  }

  return group;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of reduce and filter to achieve the expected result. This example gives you a third control over length which makes the code a bit more reuseable.

```js
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]; 
const groupNumber = 7;
const groupCount = 2;


const groupArray = (group, size, length) => group.reduce((accumulator, current, index, original) =>   
  ((index % size) == 0)
    ? accumulator.concat([original.slice(index, index + size)])
    : accumulator, []
  ).filter((single, index) => index < length)

const test = groupArray(arr, groupNumber, groupCount);
console.log(test);
```

**Step by Step**

```
const groupArray = (group, size, length) => {
  // if (index modulus size) equals 0 then concat a group of 
  // length 'size' as a new entry to the accumulator array and 
  // return it, else return the accumulator
  const reducerFunc = (accumulator, current, index, original) =>   
  ((index % size) == 0)
    ? accumulator.concat([original.slice(index, index + size)])
    : accumulator

  // if the current index is greater than the supplied length filter it out
  const filterFunc = (single, index) => index < length;

  // reduce and filter original group
  const result = group.reduce(reducerFunc, []).filter(filterFunc)

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also (apart from the existing approaches) you can have a recursive approach like this

```
function chunks(a, size, r = [], i = 0) {
    let e = i + size;
    return e <= a.length ? chunks(a, size, [...r, a.slice(i, e)], e) : r;
}
```

```js
function chunks(a, size, r = [], i = 0) {
    let e = i + size;
 return e <= a.length ? chunks(a, size, [...r, a.slice(i, e)], e) : r;
}

var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];


console.log('Chunk with 3: ', chunks(arr, 3));
console.log('Chunk with 4: ', chunks(arr, 4));
console.log('Chunk with 5: ', chunks(arr, 5));
console.log('Chunk with 6: ', chunks(arr, 6));
console.log('Chunk with 7: ', chunks(arr, 7));
```

Answer (score 0):

I able to solve the problem with this code

```js
function groupN(n, arr) {
  const res = [];
  let limit = 0;
  while (limit+n <= arr.length) {
    res.push(arr.slice(limit, n + limit));
    limit += n
  }
  return res
}
```

Comment: it wont work if we want to group the last set of element if they dont come under group of n