# How to limit questions per page in survey using Surveyjs

Tags: javascript, surveyjs

I am trying to create a sample survey page using SurveryJS. Is it possible to limit number of questions per page. Let say i have 20 questions. I want to show 5 questions per page. Any inputs will help me

Comment: SurveyJS does not allow you to set a limit to the number of questions per page. Instead, it allows you to declare which questions you want on which page. There is a demo with the full code [here in the docs](https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Library/?id=survey-customnavigation#content-result)

Comment: You can, however, write some code to convert your 20 questions Array into pages of 5 before passing them to SurveyJS: [Group array elements into set of n](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51968663/1913729)

Comment: @blex,Thank you for your input.I will handle it in java script.